# AngularJS Modular Set up

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Up until recently, I have been throwing all my function into one large JS file.  I am now trying to break these into small modules to make my application more portable per say.

I have my core js file (main.js) with the following code:

```
var App = angular.module("app", ['ui.bootstrap',  'angularMoment', 'chieffancypants.loadingBar', 'ngAnimate', 'ui.sortable', 'ngSanitize'], function ($interpolateProvider, $httpProvider) {
        $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
        $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
        $httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest = function (data) {
            if (data === undefined) {
                return data;
            }
            return $.param(data);
        };
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = ''
        + 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8';
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['X-Requested-With'] = ''
        + 'XMLHttpRequest';
    });
```

In another file (i.e. blog.module.js), I have the following:

```
        (function(window, angular, undefined) {

        'use strict';

        angular.module("app", [])
        .controller('Blog', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
            alert('test');
        }]);
    });
```

While the main.js file loads along with all its dependencies, the second one doesn't get loaded.  The controller is basically not found.  Can anyone give me pointers as to where I may be going wrong.?

Thanks

Comment: I ended up using:  [code]'use strict';

angular.module("app").controller('Blog', function ($scope, $log)
{
    $scope.hello = "Test";
    $log.log($scope.hello);
});[/code]  which worked.  Couldn't find a way of formatting this.

Answer (score 0):

The sintax in blog.module.js looks like you are trying to create two modules with same name 'app'.
Change your controller module like this

```
(function(window, angular, undefined) {

'use strict';

angular.module("app")
.controller('Blog', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    alert('test');
}]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I quote you :

```
App = angular.module("app", ['ui.bootstrap', 
...
 angular.module("app", [])
```

You **cant** redeclare a module you can either **reopen** it

```
App = angular.module("app", ['ui.bootstrap', 
...
 angular.module("app")
```

or **create** another one

```
App = angular.module("app", ['ui.bootstrap', 'app.controller'
...
angular.module("app.controller")
```